Fast quarters or slow eighths?
So I'm thinking about I'm Still Standing by Elton John. It's basically fast quarter notes in the left hand and you sort of chase the beat with the offbeat in the right hand.
Thing is I'm still not toally sure why it's one bar of fast quarters and not half a bar of slow eighths. I think it's because I sort of got used to quarter notes being relatively slow, sizteenth notes being relatively fast - I know logically those things aren't fixed but you sort of get used to them that way when you're trying to figure out how to put rhythm together.
Is it basically just a case of looking for the offbeat and the backbeat in terms of figuring out where you are? Once I've got those elements figured out I can do the switch from beat to offbeat a little bit, but I'm still really doing it by trial and error rather than really understanding what I'm doing.
Thanks

There is always ambiguity when deciding how to transcribe music by ear, and you must make creative decisions regarding how to represent what you hear in sheet music. I take in to  account a few factors:

How closely a decision represents musical attributes in the original like backbeat, meter, form, etc.
How clearly a decision will be understood by the performer, which is a very broad question and will be different for many situations in which you will be presenting your sheet music.
How portable decisions will be to musical changes later in the song.

This particular song seems to be most clearly in a fast 4, with the bass playing quarter notes and the eighth notes swung. This is because the snare is playing a backbeat, and if we understand it as a fast four, the snare lands nicely on beats 2 and 4.
Let me know if anything is not clear!

A good rule of thumb would be the general speed of the song. The song you talk about is moderately fast and energetic. So you should consider: Which of these options captures that better?

Also the song has a clear accent on the time of each bass notes, implying that each note falls on a beat.
Also usually you will find melodies to be primarily composed of 8th and quarter notes, so this is also a good reason to assume a fast tempo over small note values.

I'm questioning whether in fact it is swing. All sounds straight to me - bass/chords on the beats and &s.

@Tim try listening to the vocals

Yes.-, I have. It's a little like some of the early Elvis songs, where some of the players swing, while others are straight. But the question is regarding the accompaniment, rather than vox.

@Tim What I have notated out is the vocal line and the bass, not the accompaniment (I’m not going to create a piano reduction of this song for this question).

It's funny-- I hadn't heard this song in at least 20 years (though I listened a lot when it was new).  As I read the question I thought the answer was: "so the swing point is at eighths and not sixteenths" (the swing was that obvious from memory). I listened again, and it's not just the vocal. There's definitely some swing in the bassline (right from the pops at the end of the opening measures), and it's of course got more going on than the straight quarters or eighths depicted in the simplified transcriptions above.

To me, for something like this regardless of tempo, the ultimate decider is the backbeats should always be quarter notes on 2 and 4. If they are not then you will always be playing and reading either in double time feel or half time feel, which can become confusing in more complex charts. Another thing to keep in mind is that pop music time signatures are usually not written with a denomination of 8, with the exception of compound time signatures like 12/8 or odd time signature songs or passages.
Music should look like what it sounds like, if that makes sense.

Any time signature should be the one that makes the whole song easier to write - and read. So, using crotchets (1/4 notes) instead of quavers (1/8) may make this particular song easier for both. You say the r.h. is on the off beat, so does that mean on the & of the beats, if so, using quavers would necessitate those being semiquavers, and their respective rests, which fills each bar far more than using crotchets.
A sample of what you ask about would make the answer easier, too!
